# WitnessPubKeyHash to address

Tags: public-key

I'm trying to derive address from pubkeyhash in GoLang. Current i'm getting invalid address
Current i'm getting SegWit address but mine chain doesn't support Segwit.

```
addr, err := btcutil.NewAddressWitnessPubKeyHash(
        btcutil.Hash160(request.PublicKey.Bytes),
        s.config.Params,
    )
```

Params:

```
Name: "test",

    Net:         0xba657645,
    DefaultPort: "46464",

    GenesisBlock: &TestnetGenesisBlock,
    GenesisHash:  &TestnetGenesisHash,

    PubKeyHashAddrID:        0x8B,
    ScriptHashAddrID:        0x13,
    PrivateKeyID:            0xEF,

    HDPrivateKeyID: [4]byte{0x3a, 0x80, 0x58, 0x37},
    HDPublicKeyID:  [4]byte{0x3a, 0x80, 0x61, 0xa0},

    HDCoinType: 1,
```

Can someone help me with solving this.
I'm trying to implement rosetta-api

Comment: You are using `btcutil.NewAddressWitnessPubKeyHash` rather than `NewAddressPubKeyHash` but you don't want Segwit. Is that true?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, yes you are right, i don't want Segwit addresses

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Thanks for the tip for NewAddressPubKeyHash, i have solved the issue. +1